# asp.net login control relative url problem

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-6, virtual-directory

login CreateUserUrl="~/user/page.aspx" goes to x.com/user/page.aspx instead of x.com/dir/user/page.aspx

So I have this format for my asp:login tag:

```
    <asp:Login ID="loginMain" runat="server" OnAuthenticate="OnAuthenticate" 
            CreateUserText="Request Account"
            CreateUserUrl="/user/RequestAccount.aspx"
            PasswordRecoveryText = "Forgot Password"
            PasswordRecoveryUrl = "/user/ForgotPassword.aspx"
            UserNameLabelText="Username:"/>
```

This works in my localhost IIS7. But on my server IIS6, the site is in a specific directory (it's not a folder, just a setting in IIS), like this: domain.com/virtualdir/login.aspx

So when I am at that page, I click Request account, it goes to domain.com/user/RequestAccount.aspx which gives 404.

I want it to go to domain.com/virtualdir/user/RequestAccount.aspx

Why does IIS make the links incorrectly and not notice that I am in /virtualdir/ ?

How do I fix this?

EDIT:
It seems I totally forgot I had a Login.skin file, which is adding the link in manually, which cannot be altered. Let me do some testing.

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to be using relative path. using ~ should resolve the application relative path. i.e.: CreateUserUrl="~/user/RequestAccount.aspx"

Comment: That's not the problem. When I use ~ in the above code, it still says domain.com/user/RequestAccount.aspx instead of domain.com/virtualdir/user/RequestAccount. That tilda doesn't work right. Something must be wrong with IIS.

Comment: Is your "virtualdir" just folder or it is actually configured as an application in IIS?

Comment: configured as an application in IIS. It's not a real folder. I have multiple websites running on same server so it's necessary.

Comment: Sorry then I am not sure what could be causing that because you have it right. Just to make sure requestAccount.aspx has anonymous access and also there isn't any redirect happening somewhere in the code.

Comment: Well even before that. When you put your cursor on top of the link, it says domain.com/user/RequestAccount instead of domain.com/virtualdir//user/RequestAccount.  Could it have something to do with my Global.asax? Could Application["ApplicationHost"] be messing with this?

Comment: ..Application["ApplicationHost"]? --- depends on what you are setting it to and if you are doing any explicit url manipulation using its value.

Comment: I think that's what I'm going to use actually, I wasn't using Application["ApplicationHost"] which is hardcoded to = "domain.com/virtualdir". I'm going to use Page_Load to change the PasswordRecoveryUrl etc.  There simply isn't anyway to get ~/user or /user to work by just using the asp:login tag.

Comment: Yeah, that could be the workaround. You may use appsetting in your web.config to store your path and use it to construct your url.

Comment: Yeah only problem is. In Page_Load it's not letting me change the "PasswordRecoveryUrl"... The code is there, but it still says like domain.com/user/RequestAccount it doesn't listen to the code in Page_Load, I think it's a bug in ASP.NET or bad design.

Comment: Interesting. Did you try removing that at all from your markup and just do that in code-behind?

Comment: Ok I fixed it. Apparently Login.skin interferes with those properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to stop using "asp:login" and just building my own custom login form. Solved.